# Can BizTalk validate signatures created with OpenSSL?

Tags: biztalk

We use BizTalk to transfer files from one place to another. At the source, the file will be placed in a folder and its corresponding signature file generated using OpenSSL will be placed next to it. We want BizTalk to verify the signature file to see whether the file is intact. We want to do this because the file being read by BizTalk has actually come from a remote source and we need to validate the authenticity.
Can BizTalk do such validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   If you can write a C# helper class for it, then yes, BizTalk can call the helper class, from either a map, a pipeline component or Orchestration, and do the validation.